# SQL query for finding number of days by item by price

Tags: mysql

I have a purchase table with columns - item_key, price, recorded_at(datetime).

For any item, price changes once in a while, as we run some promotional campaigns. For instance; regular price for item_key 1 is 100 and we reduce the price to 80 for a week and then go back to regular price. The promotional price could be different at different times (next time it could be 60 instead of 80). We have around 100 items.

I am trying to write a query (mysql) to fetch number of days by item by price. My query is getting way too complex and taking more than acceptable time to return results.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "number of days by item by price"....  I assume since this is a purchase table, each entry is a purchase made... If this is the case and you want to see how many distinct days there was a purchase for each item and a certain price, I think this should work:

```
SELECT item_key, price, COUNT(DISTINCT recorded_at) from table
GROUP BY item_key, price
```

I think this should take every item_key/price pair and count how many distinct days there was a sale for that pair.

Comment: I think the issue he has is that if there is a 10 day sale, then there would only be 3 rows in the table. 1st row is the original price and the date it was set, the 2nd row is the sale price and the date the sale started, the 3rd row is the original price and the date the sale ended. With your query, it will only return 1 day of sale.